# How do I use a variable for key in Laravel config?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to access custom configuration based on the remote IP. In testing the code below works as expected if the IP is hard-coded. As written, it gives a 500 error.

$clientIp is initiated as a private variable within the class outside    of this snippet, which is simplified for use here.
The dd() test returns the IP as a string.
The odd use of config() is because of the dots in IP addresses, which interferes with Laravel's dot separator.

```
$this->clientIp = \Request::ip();  
//dd($this->clientIp); [confirming that the IP comes through correctly] 
$location = config('custom')['raspberrypis'][$this->clientIp]['plant'];
if ($location) {                                                                     
    return response('IP collected', 200);                            
} else {
    return response('Not Allowed', 401);
}
```

How do I use a variable for key in Laravel config?

Comment: What do your error logs say? I'm going to guess that maybe `config('custom')['raspberrypis'][$this->clientIp]` does not exist.

Comment: running unit tests right now - separate issue is that I cannot get logging to work under phpunit. The config entry does exist -- I can hard-code the IP and tests pass.